# Помогите подправить функцию hex, чтобы в конце хоть последний остаток снова не отображался

Tags: c++, hex

```
    #include <iostream>

int hex(int n){
  int temp;
  while(n != 0){
    temp = n%16;
    if(temp >= 0 && temp <= 9)
      std::cout << temp << " ";
    else if(temp >= 10 && temp <= 15)
      std::cout << 'A' + temp - 10 << " ";
    n /= 16;

    }return temp;
}

int main()
{
   hex(933);
}
```

Comment: Поясните внятнее, что вы хотите получить, что не получается?...

Comment: @Harry последний остаток с return temp повторно выводится

Comment: Ну вы же его сознательно выводите? Вместо `std::cout << hex(933);` напишите просто `hex(933);` и будет вам счастье...

Comment: @Harry, спасибо! (я просто недавно учу язык, т.е. при return temp, он не выводит последний остаток? или он просто все temp-ы из while-a просто в конце через return temp выводит на экран?)

Comment: через return он ничего не выводит. вы же внутри функции сами делаете `std::cout << temp` т.е. выводите переменную temp на экран. Если хотите результат вывести (или использовать по другому) уже после вызова функции, то вам надо собирать результат в строке и потом эту строку возвращать

Comment: @Mike, т.е. тут return просто выходит из функции?

Comment: `return temp` - это возврат значения из функции. Его можно использовать (как делали вы - выводя его на экран), можно игнорировать (как предложил я). На экран `temp`ы выводятся в цикле инструкцией `cout << temp;`. `return` никакого отношения к выводу на экран не имеет.

Comment: А, дошло..! спасибо

Comment: @Harry, можете пожалуйста пересмотреть код? там просто не переводит в символ, т.е. в данном примере 10 должно стать А, а становится 65 и откуда это число 65?

Comment: @Estet, от невидимого преобразования типов. char + int = int.

Comment: @0andriy, а как теперь подправить чтобы изначально не брать temp char-ом

Comment: @Estet, у вас уже именно так и сделано. Результат является числом, оператор `<<` выводит его в поток (`ostream`) как число. Подробнее можете посмотреть в исходниках реализации потоков `*stream`.

Comment: И вообще, забейте на это старьё. С++ уже не торт, там всё есть, в частности `std::hex()`.

Comment: @0andriy, ну мне бы в символ(

Comment: Вы меняете своё желание как капризная девица, то вам символ, то вам число, то снова символ. Определитесь уже. Да и как я сказал, используйте готовые методы стандартной библиотеки С++11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Как вариант:
#include <iostream>
    #include <vector> 
    void hex(int n) {
        std::vector <int> v;
        while (n != 0) {
            v.push_back(n % 16);
            n /= 16;
        }
        for (int i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if (v[i] > 9)
                std::cout << (char)((int)'A' - (10 - v[i]));
            else
                std::cout << v[i];
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        hex(933);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: а рекурсивно возможно ту же функцию написать?

Comment: А почему нет, только смысл какой?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал попроще:

```
string hex(unsigned int n)
{
    string res;
    while(n){
        res = "0123456789abcdef"[n%16] + res;
        n /= 16;
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    cout << hex(933) << endl;
    cout << hex(15) << endl;
    cout << hex(84) << endl;
}
```

Вот вариант покороче, с рекурсией:

```
void hex(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return;
    hex(n/16);
    cout << "0123456789abcdef"[n%16];
}

int main()
{
    hex(933); cout << endl;
    hex(15); cout  << endl;
    hex(84); cout  << endl;
}
```

Ну и, понятно, самое простое :)

```
int main()
{
    cout << hex << 933 << endl;
    cout << hex << 15 << endl;
    cout << hex << 84 << endl;
}
```